# Mapping through Paperclip image styles

Tags: activerecord, model, paperclip, enumeration, active-model-serializers

I have an `Album` that uses the Paperclip gem to store `artwork` image uploads. The `artwork` attribute has a list of styles of different image sizes: thumb, medium, and large.

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :artwork, styles: { thumb: "50x50#", medium: "160x160#", large: "300x300#" }
  ...
end
```

In my active model serializer I want to create an array-based `images` attribute that stores the urls of each of these sizes. Traditionally I would do something like this:

```
class AlbumSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :images

  def images
    [object.artwork.url(:thumb), object.artwork.url(:medium), object.artwork.url(:large)]
  end
end
```

Is there a way I could just map through each *style* instead of having to write the same call to the artwork url? I tried getting the hash of styles as so but got it returned nothing:

```
album.artwork.styles
=> {}
```

Any idea on getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the paperclip part (the "styles array"), but you could do:

```
def images
  [:thumb, :medium, :large].map { |style| object.artwork.url(style) }
end
```